# Customizing the Tag Helper element font

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetcore-environment

I am following below Microsoft link to change the Tag Helper element font.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I am using ImageTagHelper:

When I change the color to Green from setting "HTML razor tag helper **element**" Nothing happened.

But when I select another option "HTML razor tag helper Attribute." color of asp-append-version changes.

So, what does "HTML razor tag helper element" do. (Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors)

Answer (score 0):

I got the difference. There are two settings Within Options -> Environment -> Font & Colors -> Display Items in Visual Studio.

Setting 1 "HTML Element Name"
Setting 2 "HTML Razor Tag Helper Element".

Now because many tag helper share common name as of HTML Element name. "HTML element override font and color setting for "HTML Razor Tag Helper Element".
For example color won't change for "Image Tag Helper" because it target  which is also an HTML image element. Similary for AnchorTag Helper which target "".

But if we try with Environment tag helper like below:

```
<environment>

    <strong>IWebHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName is Staging or Production</strong>

    </environment>
```

Or, for "Partial" Tag Helper like:

```
    <partial name="Amit">

    </partial>
```